# What is a word for a mad or insane explanation? Something offered as an explanation that makes no sense at all?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

I am looking for a word that designates something as crazy but does not imply a judgment.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You need to be more specific on your question and please include context where you would use the word. Otherwise, your question will be closed as "off-topic". Thanks.

Comment: Did you try looking in thesaurus: pointless, mad, crazy, stupid, silly, ridiculous, absurd, foolish, daft (informal), ludicrous, meaningless, unreasonable, irrational, inconsistent, unwise, mindless, illogical, incongruous, idiotic, nonsensical, inane, fatuous, moronic, unintelligent, asinine, imbecilic, dumb-ass (slang), without rhyme or reason, halfwitted... The less judgemental in this list would be "illogical" or "irrational"

Comment: @145872 goofy, daffy, wacky, zany...

Comment: Do you want a noun that means the whole thing, e.g. '*gobbledegook*' or do you want an adjective that qualifies the word, e.g. 'an *incomprehensible* explanation' ?

Comment: Merriam-Webster notes that _lucid_ can mean "having full use of one's faculties : SANE" and "clear to the understanding : INTELLIGIBLE," so it follows that _illucid_ can mean the negative of these two things. Although _illucid_ isn't a common word, a Google Books search yields almost 200 matches for it. Most significantly, it seems to me to be as close to nonjudgmental as a word declaring something "not sane" or "not intelligible" can be.

Answer (score 2):

Without more context, several words might fit.  An explanation that makes no sense can be referred to as crazy, absurd, ridiculous, bizarre, insane, illogical, etc.

I might use **"preposterous"** in a context like this...

- "My brother went to the police station to report a theft this morning and you know what happened?  The officer confused him with a homonimous criminal and held him for six hours."
- "Oh, that's preposterous!"

As I said before, several other words might fit.

Answer (score 0):

I often use "illogical" for such descriptions.

i.e. "His statements are very illogical and bizarre.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Answers at StackExchange are expected to be definitive; please explain *why* you would use *illogical*, including dictionary definitions, examples, or other supporting references. Without them, your answer is simply anonymous personal opinion. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The noun *non sequitur* refers to a statement that is not connected in any logical manner to prior discourse. The inability to follow chains of logic is one the hallmarks of insanity.

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/non%20sequitur):

> **non sequitur**
>         *noun* non se·qui·tur \ˈnän-ˈse-kwə-tər also -ˌtu̇r\
>   : a statement that is not connected in a logical or clear way to anything said before it
>
> Full Definition of NON SEQUITUR
>
> 1. an inference that does not follow from the premises; specifically :  a fallacy resulting from a simple conversion of a universal affirmative proposition or from the transposition of a condition and its consequent
> 2. :  a statement (as a response) that does not follow logically from or is not clearly related to anything previously said.